Whole page, landscape figure in RevTex 4.2
I'm trying to include a circuit schematic in my paper. For this to be legible, it's going to need to be a full, landscape page.
How can I achieve this?
I've tried this but it's just spinning it in the column it would otherwise be in:
\begin{turnpage}
\begin{figure}[p]
\includegraphics{content/images/top-level.png}%
\caption{Top level electronic schematic\label{fig:top-level}}
\end{figure}
\end{turnpage}

